# C++ and Objective C in Xcode project

Tags: xcode, objective-c++

I have recently updated Xcode to version Version 3.2.2 (Pre-release). It is working fine with old Objective-C projects but I experience some problems with projects which have mix of Objective-C/Objective-C++ code. During the compilation I am getting the following error:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/functexcept.h:41:28: error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
```

I have checked the path a compiler complains about and found that file  **functexcept.h** is located in the following path:

**/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/armv7-apple-darwin9/bits/**

My question is where I should change that path to correct one in Xcode? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions about pre-release seed versions of Xcode should be posted on Apple's Dev Forums dedicated to support of pre-release seed software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make a symlink pointing `arm-apple-darwin10` to `arm-apple-darwin9`:

```
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/
sudo ln -s arm-apple-darwin9 arm-apple-darwin10
```

Report a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

After installation of the iPhone SDK with XCode (Version 3.2.1) problem has gone.